# Generated Frattini Lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $A$ be a normal subgroup of a group $G$. Let $B$ be a subgroup of
>   $A$ with the property that whenever $B_1 \leq A$ is conjugate to $B$
>   in $G$ then it is conjugate to $B$ in $A$. Prove that $G=AN_G(B)$

Help me some hints.

Comment: I might be overseeing something, but wouldn't the proof of this be **identical** with the proof of the well-known Frattini's argument??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $\;g\in G\;$ . Since $\;A\;$ is normal in $\;G\;$ we have that $\;B^g\le A\;$. But of course $\;B^g\;$ is conjugated to $\;B\;$ in $\;G\; $ so, by the given info, this means there exists

$$\;a\in A\;\;s.t.\;\;B^g=B^a\implies B^{ga^{-1}}=B\implies ga^{-1}\in N_G(B)\;\ldots etc.$$

End now the argument.